# In football, when, if ever, does shielding the ball with the foot become tripping?

Tags: rules, football, officiating

If player A is within a foot or two of the ball, and an approaching player B makes a play for the ball with his foot.

Player A places his foot between player B and the ball, and player B falls to the ground.

Under what conditions is that viewed as tripping versus shielding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Law 12 - Fouls and Misconduct; 2. Indirect Free Kick: Impeding the progress of an opponent without contact](http://theifab.com/laws/fouls-and-misconduct/chapters/indirect-free-kick) states that:

> A player may shield the ball by taking a position between an opponent
>   and the ball **if the ball is within playing distance** and the opponent
>   is not held off with the arms or body. If the ball is within playing
>   distance, the player may be fairly charged by an opponent.

This is [how IFAB defines *playing distance*](http://static-3eb8.kxcdn.com/assets/documents/IFAB_laws_of_the_game_glossary.pdf#page=8):

> Distance to the ball which allows a player to touch the ball by
>   extending the foot/leg or jumping or, for goalkeepers, jumping with
>   arms extended. Distance depends on the physical size of the player.

Also note that:

> Being in the way of an opponent is not the same as moving into the way
>   of an opponent.

So, the question scales down to which of the players are within playing distance of the ball:

- If player A is within playing distance of the ball and player A places his
  foot between player B and the ball, then it's shielding.
- If player B is within playing distance of the ball and player A places his
  foot between player B and the ball, then it's tripping.
- If both player A and player B are within playing distance of the ball, then whoever before this disputable move from player A was over control of the ball gets a decision in his favor.

Comment: What if the ball is on the way to player A and player B is running to intercept?  Does shielding vs tripping come down to the location of the ball?

Comment: If you think that this case doesn't fall under aforementioned 3 cases, then look at the 1st link I've provided. It says that: *Being in the way of an opponent is not the same as moving into the way of an opponent.* So, you shouldn't move into the way of an opponent.

Comment: thanks!! - I like that distinction! (being in the way of an opponent is not the same as moving into the way of an opponent)

Comment: I disagree with the final point. It's entirely possible to step across in front of a player who has control of the ball, when the ball is in playing distance of both players without committing a foul. Defenders do this quite often when shielding the ball out for a goal kick. In fact, if the attacker makes contact, the free kick can often go the other way.

Comment: I think the case you describe is case 1 with a minor modification: the player A quickly approaches the ball and becomes *"more"* in the playing distance of the ball rather than B. Otherwise, it's a foul and/or IMHO one of the sources of many disputable decisions made by referees.

Comment: On @RonIsaac' s comment, if B has sprinting momentum toward the ball and it is impossible for him to stop, does A still have that right to take away B's immediate forward path using only a foot.  It seems like there should be some rule overriding this rule that if someone is in a full out sprint with nothing in front of them, you can't take their immediate forward space away from them with only a foot as it's intent is clearly to trip.