# In soccer, opponent overtook me, cut me off and tripped. Whose foul is it?

Tags: rules, football

We were both running after the ball hard (I was in a direct line with the ball, he was not).  He barely overtook me, cut right in front of me and tripped on my running feet.  I don't know if there is the concept of a player's "space" in soccer, but if there is, he definitely entered "my" space and tripped himself.  Should this foul be against me? (it was called against me).

Comment: Those info are not enough to answer. It's important to know who hit the ball first and how the feet hit eachother

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In football, when, if ever, does shielding the ball with the foot become tripping?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/16005/in-football-when-if-ever-does-shielding-the-ball-with-the-foot-become-trippin)

Comment: It's impossible to give an answer, as these decisions are primarily opinion-based - even with footage, the best we could do would be a consensus. However, we certainly can provide the asker with the key considerations by stating and providing commentary on the Laws regarding shielding, position, charging, impeding and tripping.

Comment: @gdrt - I believe this question is different as it is more about body position rather than simply foot position, but I can certainly see why the community believes that these questions are similar enough to close.

Comment: As we only have your version of the story (your opponent and the referee would probably a different version), we can only try to interpret the referee's decision. Based on the few details we have, we can only have assumptions.

Comment: @Ale As I recall, neither of us had reached the ball when he (and nearly I) took the fall.

Comment: Sounds like he beat you for position to the ball and clipping the feet of a player in front of you is going to be a foul on you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of factors to consider here.

The most important is whether the ball is in playing distance.

[Law 12 - Fouls and Misconduct, Section 2 - Indirect Free Kick](http://theifab.com/laws/fouls-and-misconduct/chapters/indirect-free-kick) states:

> Impeding the progress of an opponent means moving into the opponent’s path to obstruct, block, slow down or force a change of direction when the ball is not within playing distance of either player.

If a player *barely* overtook you, and the ball is not in playing distance<sup>1</sup> of either of you, the player has committed the indirect free kick offence of *impeding the progress of an opponent without contact being made*. However, since contact subsequently occurred before play could be stopped, the offence becomes the [direct free kick offence](http://theifab.com/laws/fouls-and-misconduct/chapters/direct-free-kick) of *impeding an opponent with contact*.

<sub>1 - As [defined by IFAB](http://static-3eb8.kxcdn.com/assets/documents/IFAB_laws_of_the_game_glossary.pdf) (PDF link), *playing distance* means:</sub>

> <sub>Distance to the ball which allows a player to touch the ball by extending the foot/leg or jumping or, for goalkeepers, jumping with arms extended. Distance depends on the physical size of the player</sub>

There is a concept of personal space, or a *right to position* in [12.2](http://theifab.com/laws/fouls-and-misconduct/chapters/indirect-free-kick), but it only extends to the space you are occupying, not the space around it.

> All players have a right to their position on the field of play; being in the way of an opponent is not the same as moving into the way of an opponent.

This means that even if the the ball is in playing distance, the opposing player is not free to carelessly, recklessly or with excessive force, push, charge or otherwise knock you out of that position. However they may:

> ... shield the ball by taking a position between an opponent and the ball if the ball is within playing distance and the opponent is not held off with the arms or body ...

So if the ball was in playing distance, the referee needs to make a judgement call. Some of the considerations that would be made as part of this decision are:

- Did the opponent make an effort to shield or play the ball?

  - If so, and you had ample time to stop, or were otherwise careless (e.g. moving towards the ball at high speed, with no regard as to who was around you), the opponent will most likely receive a free kick as you have committed the offence of *carelessly trips an opponent*.
  - If before the contact, you and the opponent were fairly charging each other, and then you've continued the contact after the player has won the contest and placed themselves between you and the ball, the referee may deem this to be *carelessly charging an opponent* and also award a free kick to the opposing team.
  - If you had no ability to stop and weren't being careless, the physical contact that occurred may just be a natural consequence of an opponent placing themselves between a moving player and the ball and play. If this was the case, play would continue. It's a common occurrence for two players to fairly attempt to enter the same space at the same time and for one to come off second best.
- If the player didn't really make an effort to shield or play the ball, and their movement had the sole effect of creating contact with you, the referee may decide to award a direct free kick to you as the opponent has *carelessly tripped an opponent* or *carelessly charged an opponent*. This usually occurs if an opponent just throws their legs and not their body between a player and the ball, without making contact with the ball, or throws their weight back into the oncoming player as part of the shielding process.

Answer (score 0):

If by "player's space" you meant "a virtual circle around your body where an opponent cannot enter", I would say there is not such kind of rule in football. Two opponents have to struggle to possess the ball and that means sometimes they have to be very close to each other.

Even on corner or free kick situations, the defender will be very close to the attacker, even touching him with his chest, sometimes surrounding him with his body, marking him very closely. And there is nothing wrong about it.

On your situation, the referee interpreted that your opponent was in possession of the ball. At this moment your body can't be an obstacle of his (even if it wasn't intentional from you), hence the fault.

Comment: There's no "personal space", but there is a ["playing distance"](http://static-3eb8.kxcdn.com/assets/documents/IFAB_laws_of_the_game_glossary.pdf#page=8) term.

Comment: @gdrt, it is indeed, but this is a definition, not a rule. It doesn't mention a hypothetical player's space, as OP was implying.

Comment: -1 - There is the concept of personal space, or players having a right to their position. In [12.2](http://theifab.com/laws/fouls-and-misconduct/chapters/indirect-free-kick) it states: "*All players have a right to their position on the field of play*; being in the way of an opponent is not the same as moving into the way of an opponent."

Comment: Please don't make this about reputation, as it's both unhelpful and irrelevant. My response to this answer would have been the same if the answerer had 1, 100 or even 10000 rep. The only personal space you are entitled to (outside of playing distance of the ball) is the space you occupy. The quote makes that clear. That is the concept of personal space in football.

Comment: If the first paragraph of your answer is clarified, I'll remove the downvote. If you went one further and added some references to the Laws of the Game to support your answer, I'd most likely upvote it. I can't be expected to change my voting behaviour to take into account the length of time a user has been active on the site. It's neither feasible nor encourages strong answers.

Comment: I've reversed my initial downvote, as this answer is less ambiguous. Please consider adding references to relevant sections of the Laws of the Game, IFAB Circulars, or commentary from experienced referees to strengthen the answer.